# Output for a nested 'while' loop function in Python into a text file

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested, text-files

I have been trying to get the output for a nested 'while' loop function in Python into a text file. I know to 'write to a file' is:

```
TheFile=open("C:/test.txt","w")
TheFile.write("Hello")
TheFile.close()
```

But what should I be using when wanting to get the output of my nested loop of latitude and longitude coordinates into a text file?  I am able to get what I want from the print function but cant seem to get it into a text file...Thanks:

```
lat=-100
long=-190
 while lat <=80:
  lat=lat+10
  long=-190
  while long<=170:
      long=long+10
     print ("latitude:"+format(lat),"longitude:"+format(long))
```

Comment: Using `format()` without any format specification is useless, use `str()` instead or better go for string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use only one `TheFile=open("C:/test.txt","w")` statement, and only one `TheFile.close()` statement, and make sure they are outside all loops.

Then, you can use the `file=` argument to `print`, and otherwise keep it as the exact same `print` statement.

In your example, something like:

```
TheFile=open("C:/test.txt","w")
lat=-100
long=-190
 while lat <=80:
  lat=lat+10
  long=-190
  while long<=170:
      long=long+10
      print ("latitude:"+format(lat),"longitude:"+format(long), file=TheFile)
TheFile.close()
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: My assumption was that the OP was using Python 3.0 since he was using parentheses. Of course, that is also valid syntax in 2.x, it would just be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This prints the output as printed on `stdout` to the file. Were you using a ',' in the write() function? It treats it as two separate arguments.

More on `write` from Python shell's help.

> **write(...)**
>       write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.
>
> ```
> Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
> the file on disk reflects the data written.
> ```

Try this code:

```
with open("output","w") as f:
  lat=-100
  long=-190
  while lat <=80:
    lat=lat+10
    long=-190
    while long<=170:
      long=long+10
      f.write("latitude:"+format(lat)+" longitude:"+format(long))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

with open("out2.txt","w") as f:
    for lat in range (-90, 100, 10):
        for lon in range (-180, 190, 10):
                f.write ("latitude: {}\tlongitude: {}\n".format (lat, lon) )
```